# Angular: control / override the index of NgFor

Tags: angular

I have this `ngIf`:

```
<div class="clearfix" *ngFor="let item of result.items;let i = index">
   <h5 *ngIf="itHasOpt(item)">
      <span class="numberCircle">{{ i+1 }}</span>
   </h5>
...
```

the `i` is affected by the parent div with *ngFor for walk through the items.

My question is, how can I stop the increment of the `i` in some conditions? for example to tell the attached function if something is true to keep the `i` count as is?

Or just another idea how to control the increment of the `i`?

Comment: `i` is the index and so you can't halt the loop control.

Comment: I noticed that.. So is there another option I can handle the iteration?

Comment: without user interaction not really...

Comment: One solution would be to filter the list in code: `this.filteredList = this.result.items.filter(x => this.itHasOpt(x));`, and use that filtered list in the template.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change incrementation it's by default.  Although you can call function from controller and modify display value if you need.